# How to fix "Unable to write file" in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I tried running VS Code as an administrator, restarted my computer, but I'm still getting this error:

> Unable to write file 'e:\System Volume Information\test.py' (NoPermissions (FileSystemError): Error EPERM: operation not permitted, stat 'e:\System Volume Information')

[image: screenshot of VS Code with error]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In your own words, why do you think you should be allowed to write a Python file into that directory? Also, please read [ask]. Questions about how to use your computer are better asked on https://superuser.com; you need to *ask a question*; and we aren't interested in who you are or what your level of experience is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to write to System Volume Information, [which is a protected folder created by the operating system.](https://www.howtogeek.com/282214/what-is-the-system-volume-information-folder-and-can-i-delete-it/)
This means you can't write to or delete it, since windows needs this folder to work.
Try making a file in a different directory.